# Bug: auto-converted to tag search?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

From the blog:

> Any individual search terms which map
>   directly to the top 40 tags will be
>   auto-converted to tag searches.

tag "asp.net" is #5 in the tag list.
I entered the text in the search box of Stackoverflow

> LoadControl asp.net

I see:

> You're browsing through questions matching search terms
>
> LoadControl asp net

With the new auto-conversion of tags I expected to see:

> You're browsing through questions
>   matching search terms
>
> LoadControl
>
> within these tags
>
> asp.net

Jan

PS From the blog post it's not clear if this new functionality is also available on the other Star Wars episodes. But I suspect it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the same thing happens with ".net", "asp.net-mvc", or anything else with a period.

P.S. The new functionality is available on all of the sites.